# Jsoup html parsing style="display:none; dont show the link

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, jsoup

I'm trying to parse data with Jsoup in android. But something went wrong and i'm not html-css talented guy so i couldn't solve it. I'm trying to parse html data.But it is different in source of page and the data that i get with "check the item" in mozilla.

When i check the item with mozilla i get:

```
<a id="download_link" href="http://dl4.downloader.info/dym_down.php?id=f402e15c02f64b02da8e45535e95600a" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" style="">Download</a>
```

But in the source of page the data is

```
<a id="download_link" href="[FILE_LINK]" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" style="display:none;">Download</a> <a id="go_back" href="" rel="nofollow">Go back</a>
```

And when i try to get that data with jsoup in android i get the second one.
Maybe the problem is because of `style="display:none;"`

If it is because `style="display:none;"` how could i get that data as "http://dl4.downloader.info/dym_down.php?id=f402e15c02f64b02da8e45535e95600a" not as [FILE_LINK].
EDIT:
Link:
http://www.mp3juices.cc/download/sEhy-RXkNo0/mp3/rihanna_-_man_down/

Regards.
Omer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you inspect the element in a browser you get the DOM after javascript has run. Jsoup is a parser, so you get the html before any javascript has run. If you want to check the actual html that Jsoup will fetch press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> with chrome (I think it's the same with mozilla). That's the html response that you get from the server without any javascript modifying the content.

Baring in mind the above, the `href` attribute is being modified by some javascript code. This cannot be handled by Jsoup, since it can't execute javascript. You have to spot the javascript code that modifies the `href` attributes and execute it either with java's [ScriptEngine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html) or with a parser that can handle the execution of javascript like [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) .

I could be of more assistance if you share the link of the page that you are trying to parse.

**Update**

With this you won't have to use Jsoup anymore. If HtmlUnit doesn't suit your needs as a parser
just use it to get the complete html (after js execution) and then parse that with Jsoup and go
from there.
You have to download [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html) . Include the jars in your classpath, or use maven.

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.mp3juices.cc/download/sEhy-RXkNo0/mp3/rihanna_-_man_down/");

        webClient.closeAllWindows();

        System.out.println(page.getElementById("download_link", false).getAttribute("href"));
    }
}
```

**Update**

According to [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/629809/Android/Mobile/HtmlUnit-Android) HtmlUnit has many dependencies which render it very troublesome to make it run
on Android. Better solutions can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver) and [here](http://selendroid.io/)

**Update**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  //jQuery : Begin executing the js code when the page is fully loaded
    var $container = $('#vid');  //jQuery : Get the messages container. Irrelevant
    var Complete = false;        //A boolean
    var URL = 'http://www.mp3juices.cc/download/sEhy-RXkNo0/mp3/rihanna_-_man_down/'.split('/'); //The url that indicates the file
    var Video = '';

    function Convert(Hash) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://data.downloader.info/dym_state.php', //Internal web service of the site,  from where it get the data (download link)
            data: {
                id: Hash            //The parameters added in the url (it makes an HTTP GET request, so the url becomes like this http://data.downloader.info/dym_state.php?id=Hash where Hash is a value given as a parameter in Convert
            },
            dataType: 'jsonp',      //Google this. It's a little different from json. There are hacks for java
            success: function(Data) {   //If the request succeeds, the data brough back are in the variable Data
                Data = Data.state.split(' - ');     //Obvious
                $.each(Data, function(Index, Value) {   //iteration. Check the data that the request returns and you will understand
                    Data[Index] = parseInt(Value);  //Value variable indicates the state. 
                });
                switch (Data[0]) {
                    case 1:
                    case 2:
                        $container.append('Converting video ...<br>');  //if Value == 1 or Value == 2 
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Complete = true;
                        $container.append('The file is ready. Please click the download button to start the download.<br>');
                        $container.append('http://dl' + parseInt((Data[1] + 1)) + '.downloader.info/dym_down.php?id=' + Hash);  //This is the url that you want
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Complete = true;
                        $container.append('An error has occured. Please try to download a different song.<br>');
                        break;
                }
                if (!Complete) {
                    window.setTimeout(function() {  //Here it makes again and again the same request until it gets Value == 3 or if an error occured 
                        Convert(Hash);
                    }, 3000);   //Every 3000 millisecs (3 seconds)
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //This is executed first, and calls the Convert function from above. This here computes the hash that you have to pass as a parameter in Convert
    if (6 < URL.length && (Video = new RegExp('[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]{11}').exec(URL[4]))) {   //Straightforward 
        Video = Video.toString();
        if (URL[5] != 'mp3' && URL[5] != 'mp4') {
            $container.append('Please enter a valid format.<br>');
            return false;
        }
        $.ajax({    //Makes a GET request
            url: 'http://data.downloader.info/ytd.php', //The url that it makes the request to.
            data: {         //The data. The url becomes like this 'http://data.downloader.info/ytd.php?v=URL[4]&f=URL[5]&s=n/a&e=n/a&sig=1337'
                v: URL[4],
                f: URL[5],
                s: 'n/a',
                e: 'n/a',
                sig: 1337
            },
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(Data) {
                if (-1 < Data.error.indexOf(5)) {
                    $container.append('An error has occured. Please try to convert a different video.<br>');
                    return false;
                }
                $container.append(Data.title);
                Convert(Data.hash);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $container.append('Please enter a valid YouTube Video ID.<br>');
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the script that does the href manipulation http://www.mp3juices.cc/js/download.js . I will get back to you when I have a look at it.

Comment: Ok,Remember that I have no javascript and html talent

Comment: No problem. As soon as I have some time, I will try to help.

Comment: Thank you my friend, i'm waiting with impatience.

Comment: My friend thanks for your help.But the jars is too big.But my app is only 2.5 mb.Isn't there any simple solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with a better solution.

Comment: My friend i tried your code with html unit in java it works, but in android it gives "conversion to dalvik returned 1" error

Comment: My bad my friend. It seems HtmlUnit uses a lot of libraries that are not included in android. Please check my update and check Selendroid, AndroidWebdriver. The process is the same, but can be run on Android. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: My friend selenium forces eclipse and eclipse is giving gc overhead i edited eclipse.ini but problem didnt solved.

Comment: As it seems these libraries aren't meant to be used as part of an app. I don't have a solution for you apart from this, make a rest web service that when called, will use htmlunit/selenium and get those links, then give the result to the device. It's the best solution.

Comment: Another solution would be this, implement this http://www.mp3juices.cc/js/download.js in java. Replace the html() calls with console.log and try to run it. But if the website changes this, then your app will break.

Comment: Press F12 in chrome and check console. Run this http://jsfiddle.net/geq1LcoL/ and you will see that it prints the url you want. So if you implement this in java then you have only the links that you want.

Comment: Thanks my friend, I will try it when i,m home,but how can i run js in android

Comment: It doesnt work.I tried your js in js fiddle,it doesnt gives any output,also in adobe extendscript too.It gives compile error

Comment: Yes you re right my friend but if i run this in java how can i get result

Comment: As it is now you can't. You have to take this and replicate/rewrite the behavior in java. But as I explained before. The best solution would be to make a web service that uses htmlunit, and your android app takes the result from that web service.

Comment: But there is javascript compiler librarys in java

Comment: There is, but here you have the jquery library and ajax. I don't really know if the js compiler can handle this.

Comment: My friend as i said before im non javascript guy could tell me what does this code does what hash and how can i get that ?